# Is there any elevation profile plugin working in MVC5?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, elevation, leaflet-plugins

I have MVC5 project where I use Mapbox maps to display hiking trails (based on geojson file). Lately, I decided to add elevation profile of these trails to the bottom of the map. However, thats easier said than done. I currently use Mapbox-GL, but it seems they yet dont have any plugin which could display this profile. I was willing to switch to Leaflet if necessary but while the Leaflet itself seems to be working (and is also available as NuGet package), none of the several Leaflet plugins which display elevation do, even the simplest code from tutorial doesnt work - controlElevation is always undefined

```
 var controlElevation = L.control.elevation(elevation_options).addTo(map);
```

Did also someone else had such problem? Were you able to make your elevation profile running also in the MVC project?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MVC environment, but maybe this QA can help you in the right direction: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302023/integrating-leaflet-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Hello, thank you, but the linked topic discusses Leaflet itself which works for me. What I am not able to setup are Leaflet plugins such as Leaflet.Elevation ot Leaflet.Heightgraph

Comment: What is the order of loading of libraries? Leaflet has to be loaded before Leaflet.Elevation plugin.